# Reverse Geocoding issue

Tags: android, reverse-geocoding

I implemented the reverse geocoding in my app and it is working, but sometimes it happens a very strange issue.

The code is that

```
            List<Address> addresses = geo.getFromLocation(
                    obj.getLatitude(), obj.getLongitude(), 1);


            List<Address> address = geo.getFromLocationName( addresses.get(0).getLocality().getBytes() , 1 );


            Address location = address.get(0);
```

In the first part I get the address object of the place in which I'm. Than I want recover the generic coordinates of the city in where I'm because I don't want store the coordinates of my exact position.

This is working but I encounter a very strange issue! Trying the app with the fakegps app I set my position in "Ñuñoa", and the first address was found correctly, but when I try to get the generic coordinates, I get "Nunoa" that isn't in Chile, but in Peru!! 
That makes no sense! why this?

Thanks for helping me

Comment: I solved it! When you use the android api and you put only the name of the city, Google retrieve the first city with this name listed in the results! I resolved it creating a string that is the concatenation of obj.getLocality() + ", " + obj.getAdminArea().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure Swathi.

```
List<Address> addresses = geo.getFromLocation(msg_r.getLatitude(),
                msg_r.getLongitude(), 1);
        String geoL = addresses.get(0).getLocality() + ", " + addresses.get(0).getAdminArea() + ", " + addresses.get(0).getCountryCode();

                // reverse-reverseGeocoding
                List<Address> address = geo.getFromLocationName(geoL, 1);

                System.out.println("Where I am? " + geoL);
                Address location = address.get(0);

                // generic coordinate for the locality/city/town
                location.getLatitude();
                location.getLongitude();
```